# How can I disable type-to-search in 17.10 Files?

Tags: files, 17.10

I don't like how Files automatically starts searching when I start typing - I want it to quickly select a folder in my current folder. How can I go back to the old behaviour where typing would select a folder and `Ctrl+F` explicitly opened search?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/880121/how-to-get-back-to-type-ahead-search-in-nautilus

Comment: Ubuntu dropped it's typeahead-find patch when they moved to gnome-3.26 as no one was interested in making it work anymore. Want it back in nautilus? - either find a way to make the previous patch work or go back to 16.04